# Create navigation item using REST API with non-existing link in SharePoint Online

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, error, navigation, top-navigation

I've stumbled upon issue where I need to create a link in navigation from root site which points to site collections.

POST Request URL: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/navigation/TopNavigationBar

Body:

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.NavigationNode"
    },
    "Url": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/nonexisting",
    "Title": "Non existing"
}
```

Error response:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-2130247147, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Cannot open \"/sites/nonexisting\": no such file or folder."
        }
    }
}
```

Tried to create it manually - works fine. Got new link by REST API to check properties:

```
{
                "AudienceIds": null,
                "CurrentLCID": 1033,
                "Id": 7617,
                "IsDocLib": true,
                "IsExternal": true,
                "IsVisible": true,
                "ListTemplateType": 0,
                "Title": "Nonexisting",
                "Url": "/sites/nonexisting"
}
```

Nothing out of ordinary.

I'm wondering, is it even possible to create such links with REST API?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Could you just hardcode the response when site not existing?

Comment: Hello @MarkL
You can see the response under "Error response".
nonexisting is just some URL part, that doesn't exist in SharePoint tenant

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to this: https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore/discussions/610

In general - you need to create a navigation node that does not point to non-existing URL in your site collection, and then update URL with PATCH request.